# Installing Mediawiki on Heroku, getting 403: "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Tags: php, heroku, mediawiki

As the title says, I am not able to even run the installation.

What is going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

I am installing mediawiki 1.28.2 and following this tutorial (which has many flaws): https://klocdigitalsolutions.wordpress.com/2014/02/21/setting-up-mediawiki-on-heroku/

From heroku logs:

```
2017-05-11T17:27:19.367627+00:00 app[web.1]: [Thu May 11 17:27:19.367007 2017] [autoind
ex:error] [pid 135:tid 140342686873344] [client 10.164.78.133:52851] AH01276: Cannot se
rve directory /app/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found,
 and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: What's your step? Your OS?

Comment: I'm on Windows locally but I believe the heroku server is running on Linux. I'm on the step where he/she says "In another browser tab navigate to the heroku app which you just created i.e. <name_of_app>.herokuapp.com."

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?